# Values are being overwritten with each key addition in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetAllMemberIDsWithinATable()
{
    List<string> _sectionDataList = this.GetSectionInfo();
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    List<int> _memberIds = new List<int>();
    string _staadName = "";
    int iVal = 0;
    bool isEnd = false;

    for (int iSecList = 0; iSecList < _sectionDataList.Count(); iSecList++)
    {
        while ((iSecList < _sectionDataList.Count()) && 
               (!_sectionDataList[iSecList].Equals("TABLE")))
        {
            string data = _sectionDataList[iSecList];
            if (!(data.Equals("TO") || (data.Equals("-"))))
            {
                if (data.Equals("SP") || data.Equals("0.01"))
                {
                    isEnd = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (!_memberIds.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(data)))
                    _memberIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(data));
            }                    
            else
            {
                int jData = Convert.ToInt32(_sectionDataList[iSecList + 1]);
                if (iSecList != 0)
                    iVal = iSecList - 1;
                int xData = Convert.ToInt32(_sectionDataList[iVal]);
                for (int i = xData; i <= jData; i++)
                    if (!_memberIds.Contains(i))
                        _memberIds.Add(i);
            }
            iSecList++;
        }

        if (iSecList != _sectionDataList.Count()) 
        {
            if (!isEnd)
            {
                iSecList = iSecList + 2;
                _staadName = _sectionDataList[iSecList];
                this.staadName = _staadName;
                dict.Add(_staadName, _memberIds);
                _memberIds.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```

`_memberIds` are getting replaced while new key i.e. `_staadname` addition. like I want to have  TUB1501506,ISMC250 etc as my key and fetching them from a file and storing data in `memberIds` from

> "43 TO 62 71 72 82 92 101 TO 105 110 TO 112 137 TO 146 156 157 168 171 173 -
>   174 185 TO 188 197 198 218 220 TO 222 240 241 244 256 272 274 275 -
>   280 TO 282 285 TO 290 294 TABLE ST TUB1501506
>   63 TO 69 73 TO 77 79 TO 81 83 TO 87 89 TO 91 93 TO 100 108 109 113 TO 117 -
>   119 TO 136 189 TO 195 206 209 TO 215 217 223 225 TO 239 245 253 264 278 291 -
>   293 297 TABLE FR ISMC250
>   1 TO 4 7 TO 22 25 TO 28 31 TO 42 147 TO 155 158 TO 166 175 TO 183 292 -
>   299 TABLE FR ISMC200 SP 0.01 "

As you can see the pattern is the last string is the `_staadname` and the range give before the string are the list of `memberIds` for that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply because you only have one instance of  `_memberIds`. You never re-instantiate it inside the loop. Hence, your list is reused every iteration of the `for` loop.

Try to move it inside the loop:

```
// not here

for (int iSecList = 0; iSecList < _sectionDataList.Count(); iSecList++)
{
    // put it here
    List<int> _memberIds = new List<int>();

    // your original code
}
```